# Where is the gold?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, cipher

I made a puzzle, but it's probably bad¯\ _(ツ)_ /¯. Here goes. (CRINGY POEM WARNING)

> The fallen leader spread a plague that turned people into the undead.
>
> He got tricked by Xavier Fisher, who took all his gold.
>
> Right as he gave his last breath, he said, search, seek and destroy.
>
> Everynight and everyday people scoured the land,
>
> Except they never found Xavier and now it's up to you.

The clues in the poem are minimalized because my brain isn't big.

Clue 1

> The title suggests where

Clue 2 (pretty obvious)

> Xavier Fisher has two letters encrypted

Clue 3

> In the first line, what do the people do now?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: Search, seek and destroy could reference the song Seek and Destroy by Metallica. Seek and Destroy is also the sub-title to a walking dead book.

Comment: rot13(Gel ybbxvat zber ng Zrgnyyvpn guna gur fbat. Gur fbat vf whfg gurer gb uvag ng vg.)

Comment: I don't know if it's coincidential or not, but I found out that rot13(gur svefg yrggref bs rnpu yvar fcryy bhg GUERR).

Comment: rot13(lrf, vg jnf vagraqrq nf na npebfgvp ohg v gubhtug chggvat gung gnt jbhyq or n ovg boivbhf)

Answer (score 3):

*I think is answer is*

> Xavier escaped with a boat/ship.

---

---

*Piecing it together:*

He got tricked by Xavier Fisher, who took all his gold.

> People will sometimes have their profession like their last name, like Ryan Baker, so Xavier Fisher suggests that Xavier is a fisherman.

Everynight and everyday people scoured the land

> They did not check the sea.

Comment: this is a great answer but not what i had in mind. keep trying though!

Answer (score 3):

Before you read my solution, I want to say that it's my first time solving any riddle. I don't know how rambling my thoughts are. Even thought there are many clues I couldn't relate to anything (like the third one), I wanted to give it a try.

It's also my first time here, so I don't know what's the etiquette for answering.  I do not intend to disrespect the ones that commented and didn't posted any answers by rushing with a silly answer. I am sorry if I had to be more sure before answering.

---

> Right as he gave his last breath, he said, search, seek and destroy.

> I Google searched "Seek and Destroy" which is a Metallica's song. (Daniel C. comment)

The gold is

> Master of Puppets, third Metallica's album.

> The acrostic you made (pointed out in Ewasted's comment) reads "Three". Master of Puppets was Metallica's *third* album.
>  It was the band's first *gold* album.

> The fallen leader spread a plague that turned people into the undead.

> This could be a reference to the album's cover: tombstones being pulled by strings (the fallen leader being the puppet master).

> He got tricked by Xavier Fisher, who took all his gold.

> You said "Xavier Fisher" encripted tow letters: Xavier and Fisher both end by "ER", which could stand for Elektra Records, the record label that owns (stole?) this album.

Finnally,

> as you suggsted in you first clue, Xavier is where the gold is.
>  What's next feels extremelly forced to say so it must be wrong, but I couldn't think of anything better. The gold is on the National Recording Registry (it seemed a distinctive place for a music album to be). Xavier must be there?

Comment: this is another great answer but the place is physical